# bash populate an array in loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, associative-array

How can i populate an array in loop? I'd like to do something like that:

```
declare -A results

results["a"]=1
results["b"]=2

while read data; do
results[$data]=1
done

for i in "${!results[@]}"
do
  echo "key  : $i"
  echo "value: ${results[$i]}"
done
```

But it seems that I cannot add anything to an array within for loop. Why?

Comment: What version of bash are you using?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What you have should work, assuming you have a version of Bash that supports associative arrays to begin with.

If I may take a wild guess . . . are you running something like this:

```
command_that_outputs_keys \
  | while read data; do
        results[$data]=1
    done
```

? That is — is your `while` loop part of a pipeline? If so, then *that*'s the problem. You see, every command in a pipeline receives a *copy* of the shell's execution environment. So the `while` loop would be populating a *copy* of the `results` array, and when the `while` loop completes, that copy disappears.

**Edited to add:** If that *is* the problem, then as [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) points out in a comment, you can fix it by using [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) instead:

```
while read data; do
    results[$data]=1
done < <(command_that_outputs_keys)
```

That way, although `command_that_outputs_keys` will receive only a copy of the shell's execution environment (as before), the `while` loop will have the original, main environment, so it will be able to modify the original array.

Comment: +1 the way to avoid the subshell is to use process substitution: `while ... done < <(command here)`

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be working fine:

```
$ cat mkt.sh 
declare -A results

results["a"]=1
results["b"]=2

while read data; do
  results[$data]=1
done << EOF
3
4
5
EOF

for i in "${!results[@]}"
do
  echo "key  : $i"
  echo "value: ${results[$i]}"
done

$ ./mkt.sh 
key  : a
value: 1
key  : b
value: 2
key  : 3
value: 1
key  : 4
value: 1
key  : 5
value: 1
$
```

Ubuntu 11.10 here, bash: GNU bash, version 4.2.10(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).